# Symfony Imageboard post database schema

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I'm making imageboard in symfony. I am curios if I'm doing it in the best way.

There are threads and posts just like in normal forum.

- Thread 1

  - post 1
  - post 3
- Thread 2

  - post 2
  - post 4

The problem is I made two entities *Thread* and *Post*. It's easy to get all posts from one *Thread* but there are some problems

- I can't make `>>id` link for thread and post at the same time. the thread has another id numeration from the post. I can make another link system for example `>>t>id` but I think the same id numeration for both is better for the user.
- doubled SQL table schema - each *post* and *thread* has title, content, date, image, etc.
- fronted js functions need another parameter to know if its *post* or *thread*

and I think there will be more problems. Maybe I should use only *post* without *thread* because it's the same except *thread_id*.

Symfony won't allow making relation in one table. I can write it as a number but doctrine will be doing multiple queries which is much worse.

What should I do?

Comment: Your question is opinion-based. It will not be answered here correctly. You can post a question about your code already written and get some advice on it if you have questions. For the first point, update your post to ask what you need about your code. See [https://stackoverflow.com/conduct] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Post::class, inversedBy="children", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="parent", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $children;
```

Comment: I have problem that, it loads n+1 queries for threads and 2 queries for one thread. What Can i do?